# How to get absolute path from path with system path variables?

Tags: delphi, path, absolute-path

Is there an easy way to translate a path with system path variables to an absolute path?

So `%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\hmmapi.dll` becomes `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\hmmapi.dll`

I like to know if there is an API call that can do this, or do I have to do this the hard way and detect %..% sequences and replace them with the corresponding environment variable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the WinAPI function `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`:

```
function ExpandEnvStr(const szInput: string): string;
  const
    MAXSIZE = 32768;
  begin
    SetLength(Result,MAXSIZE);
    SetLength(Result,ExpandEnvironmentStrings(pchar(szInput),
      @Result[1],length(Result)) - 1);
  end;
```

Comment: Yes, that was the function I was looking for. I just found it myself too, after finally using the right keywords at google.

Comment: ExpandEnvironmentStrings returns the length including the null character, so you have to substract 1 from the result to return the string without the null terminator.

Comment: Added -1 to the end to strip trailing #0